# Text-Indent to hide link text

Tags: css, seo

Ive been searching for a method to replace the text-indent: -9999px css-trick used to hide link text and display images as links for say a home Logo button. Ive found a simple solution that seems to work, but doesnt seem to get any hype so Im wondering if there are holes that I dont see.
Below is the solution, with the class="homeButton" applying a css rollover image and the class="hide" obviously hiding the link text. Please let me know if this has any downsides Im not seeing as a way to still have a text based link with the text not showing up on screen normally, but still showing up in screen readers and search engines.
Thanx as always...

```
<a class="homeButton" href="index.html"><span class="hide">Home Button</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say exactly how you his the content of .hide, but if the idea is to use display:none, forget it. Elements with display-none are ignored by both screen readers *and* search spiders, as content hidden is assumed to be irrelevant (not least as black hat SEO-ers could easily stuff hidden text with keywords).

I don't really see what's wrong with the text-indent solution. Granted, I'd reduce the indent value to stop IE6 reserving memory for a huge unused canvas, but it's still the recommended technique for these efforts.

Comment: @Jimmy... Yes, display: none; Thanx, I knew it was too easy to be true. I understand text-indent is currently the way, it just seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML CODE**

```
<h1><a class="homeButton" href="index.html">Home Button</a></h1>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
h1 {
    display: block;
    width: 386px;
    height: 83px;
    margin: 11px 0 0 10px;
    text-align: left;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1 a.homeButton {
    display: block;
    width: 386px;
    height: 83px;
    text-indent: -19999px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("http://existstudio.pl/images//template/ex-ist/ex-ist-logotype.png");
}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/bartekbielawa/rmWhF/

**EXPLANATION**

the `<h1>` you can change something you like. I prefere `<h1>` because is good for SEO

Answer (score 0):

use font-size = 0

```
.hide {
 font-size: 0;
}
```